# not receiving Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Process events from real time ETW consumer

Tags: c++, windows, trace, etw

I am trying to build a consumer, using event tracing for Windows (ETW), that will receive events from Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Process. The consumer starts, there is no error from ProcessTrace. I can see my session name in the results from "logman query -ets". But, my event callback function is never called. I cannot figure out why I'm not seeing any events. I run my app as Administrator. Can anyone see a problem in my code? Thanks...

note: I tried just writing events to a file instead... my event callback was called twice, BufferCallback was called once, and in the resulting etl file, I got one event with error code 15003, which is ERROR_EVT_EVENT_TEMPLATE_NOT_FOUND (The template for an event definition cannot be found in the resource (error = %1).) I'm not sure what that means. I didn't think a consumer needs do anything with a manifest.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <wbemidl.h>
#include <wmistr.h>
#include <evntrace.h>
#include <Evntcons.h>

using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib, "Advapi32.lib")

#define LOGSESSION_GUID "{b2bcc945-9eb9-4231-883c-d6455cf4d86b}"
#define LOGSESSION_NAME L"Testing ETW Consumer"

static const GUID SessionGuid =
{ 0xb2bcc945, 0x9eb9, 0x4231,{ 0x88, 0x3c, 0xd6, 0x45, 0x5c, 0xf4, 0xd8, 0x6b } };

TRACEHANDLE sessionHandle;
TRACEHANDLE traceHandle;
GUID guid;

int bufferSize = sizeof(EVENT_TRACE_PROPERTIES) + sizeof(LOGSESSION_NAME) + sizeof(WCHAR);

auto pSessionProperties = static_cast<PEVENT_TRACE_PROPERTIES>(malloc(bufferSize));

// Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Process
// {22FB2CD6-0E7B-422B-A0C7-2FAD1FD0E716}
static const GUID MSKRNL_PROVIDER_GUID =
{ 0x22fb2cd6, 0x0e7b, 0x422b,{ 0xa0, 0xc7, 0x2f, 0xad, 0x1f, 0xd0, 0xe7, 0x16 } };


VOID WINAPI EventRecordCallback(EVENT_RECORD* pEventRecord) {
    fprintf(stdout, "Event Record Received\n");

    return;
}

ULONG WINAPI BufferCallback(EVENT_TRACE_LOGFILE* pLogFile) {
    fprintf(stdout, "in BufferCallback...\n");
    return TRUE;
}

static DWORD WINAPI Win32TracingThread(LPVOID Parameter)
{
    fprintf(stdout, "processing trace...\n");
    auto ptStatus = ProcessTrace(&traceHandle, 1, NULL, NULL);
    if (ptStatus != ERROR_SUCCESS && ptStatus != ERROR_CANCELLED)
    {
        wprintf(L"ProcessTrace exit status:  %lu\n", ptStatus);
    }
    return(0);
}

int main(void)
{
    fprintf(stdout, "entering main program...\n");
    // Set the session properties. You only append the log file name
    // to the properties structure; the StartTrace function appends
    // the session name for you.


    ZeroMemory(pSessionProperties, bufferSize);
    pSessionProperties->Wnode.BufferSize = bufferSize;
    pSessionProperties->Wnode.Flags = WNODE_FLAG_TRACED_GUID;
    pSessionProperties->Wnode.ClientContext = 1; //QPC clock resolution
    pSessionProperties->Wnode.Guid = SessionGuid;
    pSessionProperties->FlushTimer = 0;
    pSessionProperties->EnableFlags = EVENT_TRACE_FLAG_PROCESS | EVENT_TRACE_FLAG_PROCESS_COUNTERS;
    pSessionProperties->LogFileMode = EVENT_TRACE_REAL_TIME_MODE;
    pSessionProperties->LogFileNameOffset = 0;
    pSessionProperties->LoggerNameOffset = sizeof(EVENT_TRACE_PROPERTIES);
    StringCbCopy((STRSAFE_LPWSTR)((char*)pSessionProperties + pSessionProperties->LoggerNameOffset), sizeof(LOGSESSION_NAME), LOGSESSION_NAME);

    // stop any previous session
    auto stopStatus = ControlTrace(0, LOGSESSION_NAME, pSessionProperties, EVENT_TRACE_CONTROL_STOP);

    fprintf(stdout, "starting trace...\n");
    auto sTrStatus = StartTrace(static_cast<PTRACEHANDLE>(&sessionHandle), LOGSESSION_NAME, pSessionProperties);

    fprintf(stdout, "enabling trace...\n");
    auto eTrExstatus = EnableTraceEx2(sessionHandle, &MSKRNL_PROVIDER_GUID, EVENT_CONTROL_CODE_ENABLE_PROVIDER, TRACE_LEVEL_VERBOSE, 1, 0, 0, nullptr);

    EVENT_TRACE_LOGFILE loggerInfo = {0};

    loggerInfo.ProcessTraceMode = EVENT_TRACE_REAL_TIME_MODE | PROCESS_TRACE_MODE_EVENT_RECORD;
    loggerInfo.BufferCallback = BufferCallback;

    // provide a callback whenever we get an event record
    loggerInfo.EventRecordCallback = (PEVENT_RECORD_CALLBACK) EventRecordCallback;
    loggerInfo.Context = nullptr;

    // LoggerName is the sessionName that we had provided in StartTrace
    // For consuming events from ETL file we will provide path to ETL file.
    loggerInfo.LoggerName = LOGSESSION_NAME;
    loggerInfo.LogFileName = NULL;
    loggerInfo.LogFileMode = EVENT_TRACE_REAL_TIME_MODE;

    fprintf(stdout, "opening trace...\n");
    traceHandle = OpenTrace(&loggerInfo);

    // calling thread will be blocked until BufferCallback returns FALSE or all events are delivered or CloseTrace is called
    DWORD ThreadID;
    HANDLE ThreadHandle = CreateThread(0, 0, Win32TracingThread, 0, 0, &ThreadID);

    bool exit2 = false;
    while (exit2 == false)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE))
        {
            exit2 = true;
            fprintf(stdout, "escape pressed, exiting loop...\n");
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(ThreadHandle);

    if ((TRACEHANDLE)INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != traceHandle)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "in cleanup...\n");
        fprintf(stdout, "closing trace...\n");
        auto ctStatus = CloseTrace(traceHandle);
    }

    auto cTrStatus = ControlTrace(sessionHandle, nullptr, pSessionProperties, EVENT_TRACE_CONTROL_STOP);
    auto eTrStatus = EnableTraceEx2(sessionHandle, &MSKRNL_PROVIDER_GUID, EVENT_CONTROL_CODE_DISABLE_PROVIDER, 0, 0, 0, 0, nullptr);

    free(pSessionProperties);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I may have figured out a lot on my own... here's what I changed...

first, I had to include "#define INITGUID" before all the include statements, I didn't realize that needed to be the case...

then, for logfilemode in both the session properties and the logger properties, I set them to this...

EVENT_TRACE_REAL_TIME_MODE | EVENT_TRACE_SYSTEM_LOGGER_MODE

I am now getting events back to my callback, now I need to parse them and find out what is there...